# How to change my url from www.xxx.com/Magento to www.xxx.com

Tags: database, url, apache, core-config-data

I am running Magento 2.2.7 and my current URL for my store is https://shop.xyz.ca/Magneto and I would like to change it to be https://shop.xyz.ca/

I am set up on Windows Server and using Xampp 3.2.2

I don't recall where the URLs are set (not talking about Magento Admin and base URLs etc) but I assume it is within the Apache portion of Xampp. but I can't figure out where. Any help would be most appreciated as the Magento learning curve is... wow

Cheers

Comment: in your db  check core_config_data  table there

Comment: You can create a new site in apache, use this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/245741/51548

Answer (score 0):

Go to your db (via phpmyadmin)

```
core_config_data
```

open this table and search path is (keyword = url)

then it will shown the urls in value

**now you can edit as per your wish (like -https://shop.xyz.ca/)**

and cmd in your magento root directory

```
php bin/magento c:c
```

now check the site

Comment: I can change the urls in the db, that's not an issue but when I do change to https://shop.xyz.ca/, I then get an error 403 for the store and admin page. Is there something in apache I need to set? I tried to set the DocumentRoot to my Magento folder but that didn't help. I'm sure that its some step that I am missing..

Comment: you need change the url  correctly www.shop.xyz.ca/

Answer (score 0):

When you going to fresh installation of magento, please copy paste your folders and files like app,bin,dev,generated,lib,phpserver,setup,var,vendor etc....  in directly to your `var/www/html` or `htdocs` folder. You do not have to paste in magento folder. Please avoid any folder and directly paste folders files into your website root folder.

Comment: This is only for fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

Goto your database and looking table : `core_config_data` open table and search column 'path' value like `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` replace value what you want to change.

put command in root directory via terminal `php bin/magento cache:clean`  than refresh your homepage.

Comment: I can change the urls in the db, that's not an issue but when I do change to shop.xyz.ca, I then get an error 403 for the store and admin page. Is there something in apache I need to set? I tried to set the DocumentRoot to my Magento folder but that didn't help. I'm sure that its some step that I am missing.

Comment: If you receive 403 than check your folders permission.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you are running apache 2.4 on ubuntu.

[403 error when visiting website in browser](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/274304/103607)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/199201)